# What is the fastest method for reading from a text file in Java?

Tags: java, file-io

I currently use:

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Why do you need so much speed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While what you've got isn't necessarily the absolute fastest, it's simple. In fact, I wouldn't use *quite* that form - I'd use something which allows me to specify a charset, e.g.

```
// Why is there no method to give this guaranteed charset
// without "risk" of exceptions? Grr.
Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");     
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader(
                               new FileInputStream("filename"),
                               utf8));
```

You can probably make it go faster using NIO, but I wouldn't until I'd seen an actual problem. If you see a problem, but you're doing other things *with* the data, make sure they're not the problem first: write a program to *just* read the text of the file. Don't forget to do whatever it takes on your box to clear file system caches between runs though...

Comment: How on earth can you instantiate InputStream ?

Comment: Why not just do `new Scanner(new File(...))`?

Comment: @SimonKuang: I don't know how much buffering `Scanner` does, and personally I *hate* the `Scanner` API. If you're only going to read lines of text, it's massive overkill - whereas every line of the code I've given is there to do precisely one thing.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry to be rude, but can you explain why it's overkill? I would myself promote it for abstractness, syntactic homogeneity with _everything_ (if you choose), and sheer convenience.

Comment: @SimonKuang: There's a simpler type available which does what's *required* (reading text with buffering) without the added kitchen sink of all kinds of other responsibilities (parsing numbers etc). When I want a type which is there to read text and that's all I need to do, I look at the `Reader` classes, not `Scanner`. Additionally, I can then pass a `Reader` to any *other* code which is just interested in reading text. For example, I can load `Properties` data from a `Reader`, but not from a `Scanner`. I can use a `Reader` to parse XML, but not a `Scanner`.

Comment: @SimonKuang: I'd also *strongly* encourage you to pass in an encoding when constructing a `Scanner` to read from a file. Unfortunately `Scanner` won't let you pass in a `Charset`, only the name... whereas `InputStreamReader` lets you specify the `Charset`, so I can use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` as of Java 7 for example...

Answer (score 3):

If it's /fast/ you want, keep the character data in encoded form (and I don't mean UTF-16). Although disc I/O is generally slow (unless it's cached), decoding and keeping twice the data can also be a problem. Although the fastest to load is probably through `java.nio.channels.FileChannel.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, ...)`, that has severe problems with deallocation.

Usual caveats apply.

Answer (score 1):

Look into java.nio.channels.FileChannel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you benchmarked your other options? I imagine that not using a BufferedReader may be faster in some cases - like extremely small files. I would recommend that you at the very least do some small benchmarks and find the fastest implementation that works with your typical use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to read. The complete file, or from a specific location, do you need to able to seatch through it, or do you want to read the complete text in one go?

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("querySourceFileName");
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(s.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: This is the most obvious and simple way to read a file. But do you really think it can compete in terms of speed?